# Prove by L'Hospital's rule that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x}(1-\delta^2)^x)=0$, $\delta\in(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove the following with the help of L'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x}(1-\delta^2)^x=0$$ where $\delta\in(0,1]$ is a constant.

I broke up $\sqrt{x}(1-\delta^2)^x$ into $\sqrt{x}$ and $(1-\delta^2)^x$. Computing respective derivatives yields $$\frac{d(\sqrt{x})}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ and $$\frac{d((1-\delta^2)^x)}{dx} = (1-\delta^2)^x\ln(1-\delta^2)$$ and then I am stuck as to what do I do with $x$ power.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what are the assumptions on $\delta$? If $\delta = 0$ this is not true.

Comment: This only holds if $|\delta|\in(0,1]$, in which case we have $1-\delta^2<1$. Define $\Delta:=(1-\delta^2)^{-1}>1$ so the limit becomes $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^{1/2}/\Delta^x$ and L'Hopital is straightforward.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, I have edited the question

Comment: I know that I don't really answer the question, but a better way would be to use that fact that $$0<\sqrt xe^{-\alpha x}\leq \frac{\sqrt x}{\alpha x}=\frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt x},$$ where $\alpha >0$.

Comment: @Surb, I get your logic but I am trying to figure out how you got $e^{-\alpha x}$

Comment: @sunnydk: $\ln(1-\delta ^2)<0$, so, if you take $\alpha =-\ln(1-\delta ^2)$, you have that $e^{\ln(1-\delta ^2)}=e^{-\alpha x}$ with $\alpha >0$.

Comment: ooooh i got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\delta\in(0,1)$ we have $1-\delta^2<1$. Defining $\Delta:=(1-\delta^2)^{-1}>1$, L'Hopital gives $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{\Delta^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(2x^{1/2})^{-1}}{\Delta^x\log\Delta}=\frac1{2\log\Delta}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\Delta^x\sqrt x}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

I understand the the OP requires the use of L'Hopitals rule but there is really no need for that. This is a poorly designed exercise.

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt{x}(1-\delta 
^2)^x = \exp \left\{\lim_{x\to +\infty} \left(\frac12 \ln x + x \underbrace{\ln(1-\delta^2)}_{< 0}\right)\right\} = \exp \{-\infty\} = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, am I right to say that the reason why that centre portion goes to $-\infty$ is because $|\frac{1}{2}\ln{x}| < |x\ln(1-\delta^2)|$ as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: @sunnydk the logarithm grows slower than linear functions so, when $x \to +\infty$, the result is determined by the linear part $x \ln(1-\delta^2)$.

Comment: got it, thank you!